# ViewPager too Slow when Swiping(Using Picasso)

Tags: android, android-studio, picasso

I'm getting all the images from my gallery.(pictures from Samsung galaxy s5)
I can view the images from Viewpager.
But when I start Swiping. Its too Slow.
And after a few seconds, the app crashed without having error in logcat.

```
public class Paging extends PagerAdapter {
        private ArrayList<String> IMAGES = new ArrayList<>();
        private Context context;
        private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
        public Paging(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return MainActivity.IMAGES.size();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return (view == (LinearLayout) object);
        }

        @Override
        public View instantiateItem(View container, int position) {
            IMAGES = (ArrayList<String>) MainActivity.IMAGES.clone();



            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View item_view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.imagepager_layout, (ViewGroup) container, false);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) item_view.findViewById(R.id.img);


            Picasso.with(context)
                    .load(IMAGES.get(position))
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.plusbtn)
                    .into(imageView);

        ((ViewGroup) container).addView(item_view);

            return item_view;


        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
        }
    }
```

My viewPager adding adapter.

```
 viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
 adap = new Paging(MainActivity.this);
 viewPager.setAdapter(adap);
```

My XMLs..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center" />
</LinearLayout>
```

My view Pager.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Your image is too large so application will occur ANR. Try to decrease image size before load it.

Comment: how can i decrease the size of image but will be the same as viewing in my phone gallery?

Comment: Google have many answer about "Reduce image size in android". Here's an example to scale image before loading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object/823966#823966

Comment: Or using `resize` function in `Picasso` lib: http://www.101apps.co.za/index.php/articles/gridview-tutorial-using-the-picasso-library.html

Comment: I used the resiez function of picasso but some images which is portrait is became small like its landscape.

Comment: Just want to add that with the Fresco image loading library there is `setDownsampleEnabled()` method which automatically samples images at the correct size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is most probably caused by loading too much image pixel data than necessary (to fit your view size). if your images are huge in size, `Picasso` by default would load full size of the image into memory, leading to both slow frame rate as well as OOM exceptions.

a quick fix would be to use `Picasso.with().load().resize(width, height)`. It will enable `Picasso` to load a downsampled version of the image into memory. on the UI side, you could use `fitCenter` scale type for your `ImageView`.

to understand the concept better, though, i would suggest reading more on Google's developer guide on this topic here: [Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

Comment: tried to use resize, but some portrait pictures which is full screen became so small..

Comment: try adding this attribute to your `<ImageView />`  in xml: `android:scaleType="fitCenter"`, this would scale up your resized image to fit the view size. also consider trying out different target width/height when resizing.

Answer (score -1):

1.`Picasso` set mode to `RGB565`,set Memory cache and Disc Cache.

2.Reuse view in `ViewPager`.

3.`ViewPager` setPageoffset(1);

4.try:

```
<application
    android:largeHeap="true"/>
```

Comment: Did you try all the 3?

Comment: I updated it .Try to watch memory use,you can get some info in it.